Prevention of mould in air ducts
I have strong fan blowing air out of my bathroom, but it's connected using flexible duct from the shower ceiling and then to the outside, vent being fitted in the soffit. But both flexible ducts build tremendous amount of mould.
Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I've noticed it doesn't build up on plastic elements and I started thinking about building duct from PVC elements, but that's higher wizardry challenge taking layout into account.
I was looking for something covered with copper, but there are only very expensive medical grade ducts available, so that's not option either.
Really open to ideas.

If your ducts have mold, it means you are not running the fan long enough.
After a shower the fan should be run for about an hour. Doing so drys the air up in the duct. No moisture no mold.
Taking a shower then turning the fan off as one leaves the bath does not allow the air to be dried out.  You can change the fan switch out for a Bath fan timer. Set for 60 minutes before you get in the shower.

It's running about 15 minutes currently. It has "primitive" timer built in.

@Michal Fita, there is your problem.  It needs to run longer...much longer.
